# Git publish of a single branch to secondary remote repo

Tags: git, version-control

I have a team git repo that is used for active development, and a "public" repo where we publish our release code for consumption by other teams.

I'm not a git expert, so I don't know if this is something that can be done out of the box, or if what I'm currently doing is the best way of doing things.

What we need to be able to do is take the finished release code and publish it to our public repo at the end of our sprint cycle.  We don't want the other teams to have access to our team repo and we don't want the team repo branches to get pushed to the public repo.

What I'm currently doing is when we have a point release or any code we want published, I clone the public repo to a folder on my hard drive. I then copy all of the files from the dev repo's release branch into that folder.  Finally, I finish by committing those changes back to the public repo and delete the folder.

I have the process scripted out, so it's not manual, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to make the public repo a fork of the team repo, and then you could easily push the release branch from the team repo to your public repo. Something like this

```
git init team
cd team
  [do team development...]
git co -b release-branch     
  [do release refinements on release-branch...]
cd ..
git clone -b release-branch --bare team release.git
  [now you have a release repo that you can share with others]
cd team
git remote add release ../release.git
  [now you have added a second remote called "release"]
git co release-branch
  [do more refinements on release-branch...]
git push release release-branch
  [now you have updated the release-branch of the release repo]
```

It is unclear to me why you want to keep some things in just the team repo.
If you want to keep most commits in just the team repo, then you have an issue:

Due to the way git handles versions, pushing the release branch will push *all* ancestors of the release branch to the public repo. This would probably include many of the commits that you want to keep only in the team repo. 
E.g. if you merge your team repo master branch to the release branch, then all commits in the master branch will be transferred to the public repo too.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll have to look up some of those commands (Isn't --bare the same as --mirror? I really need to sharpen my GIT!)  The reason why we want to only commit the release code to the public repo is all internal politics.  No technical reasons, but it makes life much easier to have fewer commits to the other teams.